# How can I resolve "The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large."

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

When I try to get information from the TTC I receive the message "The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large."

I have searched but all the answers I have found relate to the server side, and I am sending a request for a page to the TTC.

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with TTC? Toronto public transport?

Comment: Toronto Transit Commission.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you use a different browser? What Chrome version are you currently using?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Version 36.0.1985.143 m. It says it is up to date. Another browser (IE) works and does not display the same problem.